# failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/maxim/Documents/Programming/PHP/autoload.php

Tags: php

This error: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/maxim/Documents/Programming/PHP/PHP7\Page.php'.
File exist.
Help.

OS Fedora

```
<?php 

  function __autoload($classname)
  {
    require_once(__DIR__ . "/$classname.php");
  }
  $page = new PHP7\Page('About us', 'Content');
  $page->tags();
?>
```

Comment: I see a backslash in that path.

Comment: Yes, but i can't use new PHP7/Page

Comment: Does the user executing PHP have access to this file?  It may not be the user you are logged in as.

Comment: You could use: `__DIR__ . '/' . str_replace('\', '/', $classname) . '.php'`.

Comment: Thank you it work. But i don't understand, why? This example from book and i think on other OS it's work.

Comment: It works this way because Linux/Fedora uses slashes instead of backslashes to seperate directories and filenames!

Comment: The code in the book might have been designed for Windows, which uses backslash for directories.